# dotnet core project not working in debian

Tags: debian, .net-core

I am trying to run a dotnet core webapi in debian jessie. the project is running fine on windows but when i run dotnet restore on Linux I get

"error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."
Also if i try the sample helloworld app it works on debian.

Following is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

last thing, Its actually docker container of jessie running on windows docker tool.

Comment: Can you try to (a) remove the "System.GC.Server" from config properties and also (b) make a backup of your project.lock.json, remove it and rebuild

Comment: Did both of the things that you suggested, Still got the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have .Net Core 1.0.1 installed?

Comment: @svick: dotnet --version
1.0.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to remove the "projectname.xproj", the error went away but then i started getting "Restore not found error. To fix that I deleted my project.json file and created a projectname.csproj file and added all the dependencies in it. And all started working like a charm

Comment: dotnetcore new version ie 1.0.1 does not use project.json so if your project has project.json and you want to build/run it in dotnet1.0.1 and beyond then use the command "dotnet migrate". this is gonna create all the necessay files that are needed to covert an old dotnetcore project(with project.json) to dotnet core 1.0.1 compatible project.